# View original request response header using axios

Tags: javascript, axios

When I make my web request in the firefox devtools I get two network responses

[The two responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufeYp.png)

However when I make a request using axios. Axios is only printing out the response to the second response, and I need data from the first response with the status of 302, but I only get the 200 status response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `maxRedirects` to `0` in your request configurations. https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

This should help you.

Comment: Thank you! This helped out a lot and I would have never found that on my own

Comment: Glad it helped you!